# Powershell - easy way to convert an array of ASCII values to characters

Tags: powershell

I have a restriction of not being able to encode my Powershell script file in any of the following formats
*Unicode

Unicode big endian

UTF-8*

I need to create some files with some non-english characters in their names.
I have found a way to achieve this.

```
$op = [char]24555,[char]36895,[char]30340,[char]26837,[char]33394,[char]29392,[char]29432,[char]36339,[char]36807,[char]20102,[char]25042,[char]29399    
"Write some necessary information to file" | Out-File "$op"
```

The output here is a file named "快 速 的 棕 色 狐 狸 跳 过 了 懒 狗" with "Write some necessary information to file" as its content
There are two problems with this approach

1. I find my script rather awkward looking since the script can look ungainly as the value of $op gets larger. Is there any simpler way of just storing the ASCII values and then converting them to characters on the fly. I would like to avoid having to cast all those numbers to [char] individually in the array.
2. The name should be 快速的棕色狐狸跳过了懒狗 without the empty spaces in between.

Any easy way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, you can cast the entire list to a `[char[]]`:

```
$op = [char[]]@(24555,36895,30340,26837,33394,29392,29432,36339,36807,20102,25042,29399)
```

To avoid the white space between characters, either change the output field separator prior to creating the string:

```
$OFS = ''
"$op"
```

or use the `-join` operator:

```
$op -join ''
```